# C# WPF MediaPlayer.Open проигрывает звук

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaplayer

У меня есть следующий код:

```
MediaPlayer[] sounds = new MediaPlayer[40];

private void LoadSamples()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
        {
            try { sounds[i].Open(new Uri([тут указывается путь])); } catch { }
        }
}
```

Этот код работает так, как и должен, НО во время работы цикла (когда звуки открываются) эти самые звуки проигрываются в программе, чего мне не надо. Как это можно исправить?

Сами медиа плееры создаются следующим образом:

```
private void InitializeMediaPlayers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
        {
            sounds[i] = new MediaPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А если перед `Open` вызывать `Pause`?

Comment: Не помогло, работает точно так же

Comment: Покажите, как вы создаете эти 40 медиаплееров. Вы показали не весь код. Подключаете ли вы какие-то обработчики событий, если да, то какие и тоже покажите код.

Comment: Вопрос. что это за `MediaPlayer`? Из какой библиотеки?

Comment: System.Windows.Media;